# Get Campaign name from _Sent dataview

Tags: marketing-cloud, relationships, campaign, database, data-views

I downloaded the _Sent dataview to my server. Now I need to join the _Sent data with the campaign names to filter. How can I get from the _Sent dataview to the campaign name?

Comment: using this solution the user will have to create new reports every time they create a new campaign. We need an automated process, without depending on the user for it

Comment: You are correct, but unfortunately there is no way to automate this, as campaign name does not appear in any data views

Comment: I continued researching and saw other topics saying to download the Campaign and Assets data via API and cross with the _Sent dataview using the asset's "itemID / objectID" with the "trigerersenddefinitionobjectid" in the _Sent table. It works?

Comment: Yes. You could stage metadata from the campaign APIs using an SSJS activity. Here's an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/odpulusig0yjzkq/CampaignMetadata.js?dl=0. It creates two DEs, "Campaign" and "CampaignAsset".

Comment: IMHO, this question isn't a duplicate. It's not asking about a Campaign Data View, but rather how to get the Campaign Name for a given send, "somehow".